# Pattern matching functions in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, ml

Can everyone explain to me this piece of code ?

```
let safe_division n = function
| 0 -> failwith "divide by 0"
| m -> n / m
```

When I excute `safeDiv 3 0` , what is the `m` and `n` in this case ?

In general case, when does the function match the first and second pattern ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you execute `safe_division 3 0`, first, `3` is bound to the name `n` and the right-hand side of the declaration is then evaluated.

This is a `function`, so the next argument, `0`, is matched against the different cases, in order. Here, it matches the first case, so the right-hand side is evaluated and an exception is thrown. In this case, the name `m` is never bound to anything.

If the second argument was, for example, `1`, then it would have matched the second case (this case matches every possible value anyway, it's a default case), binding the name `m` to the value `1` and then returning the result of `n / m`.

Answer (score 14):

It is easy to see what this means once you realise that

```
let f x y z = e
```

is just a short-hand for

```
let f = function x -> function y -> function z -> e
```

That is, a function of n arguments actually is n nested functions of 1 argument. That representation is called "currying". It is what allows you to apply a function partially, e.g.

```
let g = f 3
```

returns a function of 2 arguments.

Of course, the short-hand above can be mixed freely with the explicit form on the right, and that's what your example does. You can desugar it into:

```
let safe_division = function n -> function
                                  | 0 -> failwith "divide by 0"
                                  | m -> n / m
```

Answer (score 7):

```
let safe_division n
```

define a function which type is int -> ...

```
function
| 0 -> failwith "divide by 0"
| m -> n / m
```

define a function which type is int -> int

So the resulting type of the whole is *int -> int -> int* where n is the first argument, and m the second. The last int is the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
let safe_division n = function
| 0 -> failwith "divide by 0"
| m -> n / m
```

is just equivalent to:

```
let safe_division n = fun x -> match x with
| 0 -> failwith "divide by 0"
| m -> n / m
```

Note `fun` and `function` are slightly different. See: [Function definition](https://v2.ocaml.org/releases/5.0/manual/expr.html#sss:expr-function-definition).